# DI Container IServiceProvider: Callback for unresolved types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ioc-container

I'm using the default DI Container from Asp.net Core and I have multiple IServiceProvider instances which I need to nest.

*I know that the default DI Container doesn't support nesting by itself and that alternatives do, but if possible I don't want to switch.*

Until now I only need to resolve types were it and its dependencies were always in the same container. In this case my self-rolled superficial nested ServiceProvider could properly resolve the types by simple first checking the child container and then the parent container if it couldn't find it in the child container.
But now I have a type that I want to resolve which is registered in the child container and has dependencies on types registered in the parent container.
In this case my self-rolled solution fails.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to provide a callback which is called when the ServiceProvider is not able to resolve one of the dependencies.
The callback would then resolve the type and return an instance of the needed type.

With this I could provide a callback which would use the parent container to resolve the needed type.

An example of what I'd like to do (Interfaces omitted for brevity):

```
    public class A {  }
    public class B { public B(A a) { } }

    public class ServiceProviderFallBack {
        private ServiceProvider rootServiceProvider;
        public ServiceProviderFallBack(ServiceProvider rootServiceProvider) => this.rootServiceProvider = rootServiceProvider;
        public object Resolve(Type type) => rootServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(type);
    }

    public void Run() {
        var rootServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        rootServiceCollection.AddSingleton<A>();
        var rootServiceProvider = rootServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var webApiServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        //How could this be done, if it can be done at all?     
        webApiServiceCollection.AddSingleton(new ServiceProviderFallBack(rootServiceProvider)); 
        webApiServiceCollection.AddTransient<B>();
        var webApiServiceProvider = rootServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        webApiServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<B>();
    }
```

I'd like the ServiceProvider `webApiServiceProvider` to use the registered type `ServiceProviderFallBack` when it is unable to resolve a type and use the `ServiceProviderFallBack.Resolve` method for that instead.

The example is strongly simplified: The ServiceProviders `rootServiceCollection` and `webApiServiceProvider` are in different assemblies.

Comment: I'd classify this under the heading of XY Problem. Why do you feel you need nested service collections in the first place? I can't think of any rational reason.

Comment: I could probably think of multiple but in this particular case I have multiple modules which use the root ServiceProvider to fulfill their dependencies. One of the modules runs a asp net core instance which creates its own ServiceProvider which I need to nest since some types (e.g. controllers) are in the child ServiceProvider and it is possible that their dependencies are registered in the parent ServiceProvider.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you need this type of segregation of service collections. The app should only be concerned about its services. Any libraries should be using abstractions fulfilled by the app that uses the library. I see no need for more than a single service collection.

Comment: If you're trying to do something like segregate services used for an API vs service used for MVC or whatever, all in the same app then: 1) that seems like a bad idea regardless, and 2) if you do truly want that, it's an argument for separating the apps, not the service collections.

Comment: I don't particularly want it separated but it is a consequence of instantiating asp.net core which will use its own ServiceCollection/ServiceProvider. Sure I could have separated it into two apps, but those parts share objects and separating them would have made the communication between them that much more complex. And since I've already made the decision to keep it in the same project, I'd rather switch the container than rework everything again which could just as well lead to other roadblocks.

Comment: And why can't you use the service collection from ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Because the Asp.net Core instance is only a module and it is possible that it is never used

Comment: But it's not just a module. It's your app. It's either ASP.NET Core or it isn't. All the DI layer, logging, configuration, etc. is all independent, and can be included with or without the ASP.NET Core components. However, as soon as you do, you have an ASP.NET Core app. Period. If you're doing other things, your app is doing too much.

Comment: The point I'm making is one of app design. It's somewhat subjective, but at a high level, there's a right or wrong way to go about something. When you start hitting friction like this, where you're fighting with the framework, it's a pretty clear sign the app design is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198560/discussion-between-arokh-and-chris-pratt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, no it is not possible with the current implementation.
I had a look at the source code and there is no way to add a callback.

The relevant part can be found here:
[DependencyInjection/src/DI/ServiceLookup/CallSiteFactory.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/DI/ServiceLookup/CallSiteFactory.cs)

Once a type is requested `GetCallSite` is called which calls `CreateCallSite` upon the first request. And then in the case for simple registrations has the following callchain:

```
CreateCallSite 
> TryCreateExact 
> TryCreateExact 
> CreateConstructorCallSite 
> CreateArgumentCallSites 
> GetCallSite
> CreateCallSite (If not already cached)
```

I have found no part which could be replaced with custom classes or where callbacks could be used.

After that didn't work out I found [OrchardCore/Environment/Shell/Builders/Extensions/ServiceProviderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/blob/master/src/OrchardCore/OrchardCore/Environment/Shell/Builders/Extensions/ServiceProviderExtensions.cs) which does what I'd like to do, but I had issues with duplicate registrations.

So I abandoned the generalized approach and went with something more localized:
Instead of trying to link the two ServiceProviders I keep them separate and just add the necessary services to the "child" ServiceProvider.